Implementing Deep Linking for Website-to-App Redirection in React Native
When a user visits certain pages on a website, and they have the app installed, I’d like the app to open instead. I’m not entirely sure how to achieve this, but I assume it involves adding a meta tag or similar functionality to the pages.
For example, if the hosted website is https://example.com/ and a user visits https://example.com/stream, I’d like the XYZ application to open (if installed) and load the stream page within the app.
This functionality needs to be implemented in React Native. While I’m familiar with handling deep linking, this approach seems to require a different method.
